# How to Monitor Browser/Client driven WebPage

Tags: html, monitor

How would you monitor this web page for changes?

The HTML doesn't change but what gets displayed does.

http://otce.finra.org/DLSymbolNameChanges

z

Comment: I'll look at their source code. What have you tried?

Comment: I found that there is an jquery object that constructs the table. Each screenshot includes the findings in the webpage. The link is [here](https://www.scribd.com/doc/293496540/Images-for-OTCE-Table).

Comment: I've tried Curling the webpage....but it doesn't work because the actual content is generated in the browser apparently.

Comment: Yes, getData is somewhere in the script that has v.handle = h = function(n) {
  return typeof i != "undefined" && (!n || i.event.triggered !== n.type) ? i.event.dispatch.apply(h.elem, arguments) : t
}

Comment: So would I have to write a script that evaluates getData and mimics what a browser would do?

How would that be done?

Comment: I am parsing the files to look for the raw data. The jquery is [here](http://otce.finra.org/bundles/jquery). The js is [here](http://otce.finra.org/bundles/js?v=t7KMHOt44y7ufExaPCTa6GvHB9b0gv5-otLPcLlOl4s1).

Comment: And lying in plain sight is `var otceGrid = new OTCEGrid("#tblSymNameChanges", "/DLSymbolNameChanges/DLSymbolNameChangesJson");`, the url to some data. I'll reply later with more again.

Comment: What OS do you have?

Comment: Win 7 Ultimate ..... x64 .....and THANK YOU for helping with this!!!

Comment: Clayton....could you send me an EMail pls: KongATSignHereLightHouse57.com

z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download Python 2.7 from [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-279) and install it.

I have made a python program that checks if the file has changed. Don't be scared by the format. Here is the [file](http://www.filedropper.com/monitor). It is a `.zip` file. Extract the files to a folder. Run `setup.bat`, and then you should be able to just run `main.py`.

**Quit `main.py` by Control-C, not the "X".**

**EDIT: File no longer available because someone wants to take pictures of their new PC :(**

Comment: I've added a + Vote.....won't show up cause I'm new.......is there any other way to add votes to you/add to your rep?

Comment: Does the program work? There were no changes when I tested it.

Comment: I haven't tried it yet......but your solution will work I'm sure. Will let you know. Meanwhile will mark it as the answer..... Thank you again.

Comment: OK. I installed it and it is running fine. Changed a few directories in the setup.bat file because I install programs on another drive besides C:

Is there a way to change it to check every 60 seconds?

I will look at the Python code and see if I can do that. 

Will look up Python programming and see if it can splash an alert on the screen when it finds any changes.

I am well versed in Javascript, PHP, etc, so will probably not be an issue.

Will keep you posted.........also once again THANK YOU!

Comment: Changed the 60*10 to 60*1 and now it's checking every 60 seconds........Cool........Now will find out how to set an alert and have it running in the background while I play with stocks.....lol.

Comment: It should change the title and start a command prompt, but you can personalize it, too.

Comment: Seems that doing an alert box in Python is a bit involved. Still researching it. Tried a few things w/o success. Ideally it should run in the background and then play an audio file when changes happen....and open a javascript type pop up window.....or just a small regular window I guess...I have something for you: HB atsigngoeshere LightHouseNova.com ..........z